# Decimal to Binary in C

Tags: c, pointers, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I'm creating a program that adds and subtracts 2 numbers. Then I have to output this answer into different bases.

My answer is in decimal format, of type long double, such as:

```
long double answer;
answer = numberOne + numberTwo;
```

I want to convert this answer into binary. Now I have code used earlier in my program that does this, but with a char pointer:

```
char * decimalBinary (char * decimalNumber) 
{

    bool zeroFront = true;
    int i;
    int z;
    int j = 0;
    int n = atoi(decimalNumber);
    char * binaryNum = malloc(32+1);
    binaryNum[32] = '\0';

    int current_index=1;
    int end_index = strlen(decimalNumber)-1;

    //Error check for valid decimal input, needed error check for beginning of code
    while(current_index <= end_index)
    {
        if(decimalNumber[current_index] != '0' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '1' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '2' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '3' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '4' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '5' &&dec[current_index] != '6' &&dec[current_index] != '7' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '8' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '9')
        {
            binaryNum[0] = -8;
            return binaryNum;
        }
        current_index++;
    }


    for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        z = n >> i;

        if (z & 1) 
        {
            binaryNum[j] = '1';
            j++;
            zeroFront = false;
        } 
       else if (!zeroFront) 
       {
            binaryNum[j] = '0';
            j++;
        }
    }

    binaryNum[j] = '\0';

    return binaryNum;
}
```

My preferred solution is to use the code I already have in my program to convert my answer into a binary format, but as you can see the parameters are conflicting, and I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Another possible solution that detracts from having reusable code in my program, is to create a different function all together that converts a decimal to a binary, but accepting a parameter of type long double, which is a bit unclear to me as well.

Edit:
Instead of `long double`, my answer is of type `int`.

Comment: Converting a `long double` in binary is much different than converting a `int` into binary (that's what your code do). Are you sure it is what you want ? What result do you expect by converting 1.5 into binary format ?

Comment: Yes, I believe I should change long double to int

Comment: Your `answer` is in whatever format the system uses to represent its type.  Whether that type is `int` or `long double`, its format is unlikely to be well characterized as "decimal".

Comment: Are you aware `long double` is a floating-point format? You'll have do deal with quite a big range of values (possibly you will need to add some 'E+exp` suffix) and with fraction part.

Comment: The line `if(decimalNumber[current_index] != '0' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '1' … '9')` should be `if (!isdigit(decimalNumber[current_index]]))`, arguably with a cast to `(unsigned char)` for the argument.  If you have to write almost the same thing out multiple times like that, you should cultivate a sense that something is wrong — and find a way to avoid repeating yourself.  One of the principles espoused in [The Pragmatic Programmer](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer) is DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: You should look to `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` since it tells you where it stops converting the string, which would radically simplify the checking.

Comment: You will also need to look into [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672).  Your desire to reuse code is admirable; you should when you can.  But it is necessary to have good code to reuse.  Your current function combines two separate tasks: converting a string to a number and converting a number to a (binary) string.  You need to separate these into two separate functions.  You might also create a cover function that keeps the current name and interface but calls on the new functions to do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to reuse your function without modifications, you can transform `answer` into a decimal string and pass the string to your function.

```
char stringAnswer[20];
sprintf(stringAnswer, "%d", answer);
printf("the binary answer is %s\n", decimalBinary(stringAnswer));
```

But a better solution should be to split the function `decimalBinary` into two functions : the first one to check that all digits are ok, and the second one to convert a `int` into a binary string.
Then you'll be able to call directly this second function with `answer` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a magic number 32, better to let the compiler deduce the needed size as an `int` is not always 32 bits.  Checking allocation results is a good habit.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INT_MAX_BIN_WIDTH (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)
char * binaryNum = malloc(INT_MAX_BIN_WIDTH+1);
assert(binaryNum != NULL);
binaryNum[INT_MAX_BIN_WIDTH] = '\0'; // null character
```

---

Rather than checking against each digit, since `'0'` to `'9'` must be sequential:

```
// if(decimalNumber[current_index] != '0' &&decimalNumber[current_index] != '1' ...
if (decimalNumber[current_index] < '0' || decimalNumber[current_index] >= '9') ...
// or
if (!isdigit((unsigned char) decimalNumber[current_index])) ...
```

---

Problem does not address negative numbers.  Better to state that they will not occur or better, make code handle them.

---

Code allocates memory, but does not free it.  Consider letting the higher level code allocate/free and supply the needed buffer to `decimalBinary(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src)`.  Robust code would supply the size too.

```
char *binaryNum = malloc(INT_MAX_BIN_WIDTH+1);
assert(binaryNum != NULL);
decimalBinary(binaryNum, INT_MAX_BIN_WIDTH+1, "123");
do_something(binaryNum);
free(binaryNum);
```

---

Following is a solution that is not limited to 32 bits.  It does not cope with negative numbers nor memory allocation - certainly it should provide some ideas for your eventual solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void times10(char *binaryNumber, int carry) {
  size_t length = strlen(binaryNumber);
  size_t i = length;
  while (i > 0) {
    i--;
    int sum = (binaryNumber[i] - '0') * 10 + carry;
    binaryNumber[i] = sum % 2 + '0';
    carry = sum / 2;
  }
  while (carry) {
    memmove(&binaryNumber[1], &binaryNumber[0], ++length);
    binaryNumber[0] = carry % 2 + '0';
    carry /= 2;
  }
}

char *decimalBinary(char *binaryNumber, const char *decimalNumber) {
  strcpy(binaryNumber, "0");
  int ch;
  while ((ch = *decimalNumber++) >= '0' && (ch <= '9')) {
    times10(binaryNumber, ch - '0');
  }
  return binaryNumber;
}

int main(void) {
  char buf10[200];
  puts(decimalBinary(buf10, "123"));
  puts(decimalBinary(buf10, "123456"));
  puts(decimalBinary(buf10, "123456789012345678901234567890"));
  return 0;
}
```