# Changing function to accept integer instead of char pointer to convert binary to octal and hex in C

Tags: c, binary, hex, octal

Currently I have code for converting a char pointer that holds binary characters and converts them to hex and octal representations.

The way my code has progressed, I now have an integer binary number, it is no longer a char pointer, but I still want to convert it to either hex and octal.

So, the code I have converts: "1101" into a hex or octal equivalent, but I current have 1101 as an integer value, but still want to convert that to hex or octal.

I do not know how to rewrite the code to accept an integer binary as an argument instead of a char * binary. Or how to change the int I have into a char pointer so that it can successfully go through the conversion function.

Here's the code for the function call that current works with a char pointer to a binary representation of a number, converting it into an octal or hex representation:

```
output = binaryBaseChange(output, 3); //for binary to octal conversion
output = binaryBaseChange(output, 4); //for binary to hex conversion
```

Here's the conversion function using the char * bin argument:

```
char * binaryBaseChange (char * bin, int size_of_digit) {
int offset = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 4;
int k = 0;
int number_of_hex_digits = 0;
char* substr;
char * out;
int r = 0;


while(((strlen(bin) + offset) % size_of_digit) != 0) {
    offset++;
}

out = malloc((strlen(bin) + offset) / size_of_digit+1);
out[(strlen(bin)+offset)/size_of_digit] = '\0';

r = (int)strlen(bin) + offset;

bin = pad_bin(bin, r);
number_of_hex_digits = (int)strlen(bin)/size_of_digit;

while (k < number_of_hex_digits) {
    substr = strndup(bin+i, j);
    substr[size_of_digit] = '\0';

    i = i + size_of_digit;
    j = j + size_of_digit;

    if (size_of_digit == 4) {
        out[k] = single_digit_bin_to_hex(substr);
    } else if (size_of_digit == 3) {
        out[k] = single_digit_bin_to_oct(substr);
    }
    free(substr);
    k++;
}
free(bin);
out[k] = '\0';
return out;
 }
```

Here are the functions called within the conversion function:

```
char single_digit_bin_to_oct (char * bin_dig) {
if (strcmp(bin_dig, "000") == 0) {
    return '0';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "001") == 0) {
    return '1';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "010") == 0) {
    return '2';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "011") == 0) {
    return '3';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "100") == 0) {
    return '4';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "101") == 0) {
    return '5';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "110") == 0) {
    return '6';
} else {
    return '7';
}
}

char single_digit_bin_to_hex (char *bin_dig) {

if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0000") == 0) {


    return '0';
 } else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0001") == 0) {

    return '1';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0010") == 0) {

    return '2';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0011") == 0) {

    return '3';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0100") == 0) {

    return '4';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0101") == 0) {

    return '5';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0110") == 0) {

    return '6';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0111") == 0) {

    return '7';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1000") == 0) {

    return '8';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1001") == 0) {

    return '9';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1010") == 0) {

    return 'A';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1011") == 0) {

    return 'B';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1100") == 0) {

    return 'C';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1101") == 0) {

    return 'D';
} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1110") == 0) {

    return 'E';


} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "1111") == 0){

    return 'F';
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR");
    return 'X';
}
}


char * pad_bin (char * bin, int n) {
int bin_len = (int)strlen(bin);
int dif = n - bin_len;
char * new_bin = malloc(n + 1);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

memset(new_bin,0,n+1);

if (n == 0) {
    return bin;
} else for (;i <= n; i++) {
    if (i < dif) {
        new_bin[i] = '0';
    } else {
        new_bin[i] = bin[j];
        j++;
    }

}


return new_bin;
}
```

Comment: do you need `int to binary string`? E.g `12 -> "1100"`

Comment: Right now I have 1100 which is an integer in binary, and I want to convert that to hex or octal. But the code I have converts "1100" a string (more specifically a char pointer), into hex or octal. I don't know how to rewrite the code to convert an int, not a char pointer.

Comment: Instead of rewriting the function you could go the lazy route and write a wrapper for it that changes your int into a char pointer that the function will recognize.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? Because I did think of that, but I am having the hardest time in figuring out how to change my int into a char pointer.

Comment: you want `sprintf(binstr, "%d", intbin);`

Comment: So just to clarify, is doing this: char binstr[] = ""; sprintf(binstr, "%d", intbin); fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", binstr); binstr =   binaryBaseChange(binstr, 3);       Valid? I'm testing it myself, but I just want to double check with those with more experience using sprintf.

Comment: So apparently there are some issues with char binstr[]="". Will change to char*binstr =NULL and see if that works.

Comment: `char binstr[16];sprintf(binstr, "%d", intbin); char *output =  binaryBaseChange(binstr, 3);`

Comment: Please note my comments [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231935/decimal-to-binary-in-c#comment50467480_31231935) and [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231935/decimal-to-binary-in-c#comment50467622_31231935) to your earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231935/decimal-to-binary-in-c).  Your code is repeating itself.  I'm not convinced by the basic algorithmic choice here, but at least use an initialized array plus a loop to replace the blocks like `} else if (strcmp(bin_dig, "0011") == 0) {

    return '3';
}` in your code above.

Comment: there is a problem with the initial parameter 'bin'   in some cases, depending on the actual length/value in 'bin', the passed in parameter will be passed to free()  in other cases, a locally malloc'd pointer will be passed to free().  So, depending on the input data, the callers' 'bin' may or may not be passed to free().    The problems originate in the function pad_bin().   Suggest: always return new_bin, after copying the contents of 'bin' to 'new_bin'

Comment: for readability by us humans, please use consistent indentation.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Note: never use tabs for indenting because every editor/wordprocessor has their tab width/tab stops set differently.

Comment: rather than calling strlen() over and over and over, call it once and keep the result in a local variable.

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful